# Riemannian curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

When I calculate the Riemann curvature $R(X,Y)Z$ in a local coordinate system, why does the Lie bracket vanish?
Is this true only for a Riemannian Manifold?

Comment: The lie brackets don’t vanish. They are there all the time and are required to ensure the curvature is coordinate independent. They vanish only when you use coordinate vectors for X and Y. Actually for any pair of vectors whose lie brackets vanish which includes coordinate vectors. To understand why, you need to know what a lie bracket is.

Comment: Ricci flow facilitates this, multiplicative functions are continuous to their norm, each norm being an element of curvative i.e an operator equal to some integer.